Missing SRI hash version in python environment
I'm trying to use Panel for the first time in Jupyter Notebook. I've pip installed it and trying to just run in my python environment:
import panel as pn
however I get this error: ValueError: Missing SRI hash for version 3.3.4
I've been trying to find out what SRI hash is and how to install said version, however I'm failing miserably in trying to understand how it applies to python environments. Any help will be appreciated.

What versions of Jupyter & Python are involved here? How did you install it?  Since you say, " trying to use Panel for the first time in Jupyter Notebook", any chance you are you just trying to try working in Panel and don't specifically need to have it on your local machine right now? I ask because I just ran it fine on a remote machine in a temporary session launched from here and I could tell you how to access it if you'd like?

I'm using jupyter notebook and python version 3.11.8 and conda installed Panel. I'd ideally like to run it on my local machine

In the original post you mention, "I've pip installed it"? Do you mean Jupyter? Either way, you should be doing as much as you can in one package manager and avoid mixing in matching. Usually if you've opted for conda/Anaconda, you are best to stick with that and only ever deviate for things that don't have a conda recipe. That is just a general best practice. I'm not suggesting it is involved here as the underlying issue. But I'll add that Usang is suggesting use of pip in his answer, but perhaps ideally it should be a %conda install-route being suggested?

sorry, I meant pip install, not conda install. I've tried both, but I get the same issue

The panel library uses SRI (Subresource Integrity) to verify the integrity of JavaScript and CSS files it loads from a CDN. To resolve this issue, you can specify the version of panel and install the specific version. Try uninstalling the current panel version and reinstalling a specific panel version.
!pip uninstall panel -y
!pip install panel==3.3.4

Please adopt current best practice for installs inside Jupyter, UsangR01. You should no longer be using, or suggesting others use, an exclamation point in conjunction with installs done inside a cell of a running Jupyter Notebook. This has not been the way since 2019. You should be using the magic version, %pip install, inside a cell in a running notebook to do installs in an active running .ipynb file. That ensures the commands target the environment where the kernel backing the notebook is running. The exclamation point used in conjunction with install commands doesn't do ...

  that and so it may lead to unexpected outcomes.  See more about the modern %pip install command here added in 2019 for a better experience with such installs performed from in a cell inside a running notebook. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. ( The magic version is pretty much ...

 universal works in JupyterLite and even Google Colab now.)

I get the following error if I try to install that version of panel: ERROR: No matching distribution found for panel==3.3.4

I've just checked the available versions for panel (https://pypi.org/project/panel/#history), and it looks like the latest stable version is '1.4.4' which was released 31/5/2024.
Now you can uninstall and reinstall this new version:
%pip uninstall panel -y
%pip install panel==1.4.4
You should then be able to import panel and load the extension:
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
